# Empty generator

Tags: python, generator

Playing around with trees, I stumbled over this behaviour:

```
def descendants (self):
    return #or "pass" or "42"
```

obviously returns `None`.

On the other hand side:

```
def descendants (self):
    return
    yield 42
```

returns a generator which yields nothing (actually the behaviour I needed for leaf nodes).

**Could somebody explain to me what is happening under the hood here?**

**Shouldn't the `yield 42` be unreachable code?** (I guess the decision whether a function is a generator or a "normal" function is made at compile time, based on whether it contains one or various `yield` statements, be they reachable or not. But this is just a shot in the dark.)

---

The context is the following: I have trees and each node is either a tree or a leaf. Now I want to generate all the descendants of a node:

```
class Leaf (Node):
    @property
    def descendants (self):
        return
        yield 42

class Tree (Node):
    @property
    def descendants (self):
        for child in self.children:
            yield child
            yield from child.descendants
```

Comment: I usually just `return ()`, as it acts about the same as an empty generator.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, the `yield` keyword inside a function is detected at compile-time. The result is that the function no longer behaves like a normal function. When a function with a yield keyword is called, the function IMMEDIATELY returns a lazy generator object which produces variables as needed according to the defined  function. The code in your function is only run when the generator is iterated through.

It's more succinctly explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6400990/2980246)

So `descendants` is called, and since the `yield` keyword is present in the function, a generator object is immediately returned. Since `descendants` immediately `return`s, however, the generator yields no values-but it's definitely still a generator.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found the linked question, but failed to scroll down to the answer you linked. Let me digest this a bit.

Comment: Do you have any links to language docs, as this doesn't say anything: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#generators

Comment: @JesseMu +1 You've made clean and accurate explanation.

Comment: @Hyperboreus yeah, the docs don't make it very clear. I think it's implicit in the idea that the generator "resumes where it left off" once `next()` is called.

Comment: @Hyperboreus see the generator object, explains slightly better https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-generator

Comment: @RaymondHettinger +1 from me, too, but: Am I the only one here who thinks that it is somewhat strange that unreachable code makes a difference? At a minimum, it doesn't comply with the principle of least surprise... (same as: `def f(): print(x); return; x = x` while having an `x` in the enclosing scope).